Question about Vandermonde's Identity
This is a practice problem I found online:

Twelve 1's and ten -1's are written on a chalkboard. You select 10 of the numbers and compute their product, then add up these products for every possible way of choosing 10 numbers from the 22 that are written on the chalkboard. What is the sum of all these products?

My idea to solve this problem was to reformulate it as a sum. Specifically, fix $k$, the number of $-1$s we choose. Then, the sum of all products of 10 chosen numbers with exactly $k$ $-1$s is given by $\binom{12}{10 - k} \binom{10}{k} (-1)^k$. The sum of all such products is then just
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{10} \binom{12}{10 - k} \binom{10}{k} (-1)^k
$$
Now, I know that by Vandermonde's Identity, we have
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{10} \binom{12}{10 - k} \binom{10}{k} = \binom{22}{10}
$$
However, the $(-1)^k$ factor seems to mix everything up. To compute the desired sum, I would need to somehow find the sum of all $\binom{12}{10 - k} \binom{10}{k}$ with only odd $k$, which I'm not sure how to do.
Another idea I considered was applying the binomial theorem, due to the presence of the binomial coefficients. However, I'm not sure what this would look like, exactly.
Am I on the right track? Can someone provide a solution to this question?

Do you know how to prove Vandermonde's identity? If yes, modify the proof to account for the $-1$. Hence, what could the expression simplify to?

Recall that the proof of Vandermond's identity follows from calculating the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in two ways:
$$ (1 + x)^{12}(1+x)^{10} = (1+x)^{22}.$$
Let's modify this to calculate the desired expression. We want the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in:

 $$(1+x)^{12} (1-x)^{10}. $$

To make it easier to calculate, we manipulate it via the following form:

 $$ (1+x)^2 (1-x^2)^{10}. $$

Hence, the answer we're looking for is:

 $${ 2 \choose 2 } \cdot {10 \choose 4 } - {2 \choose 0} \cdot { 10 \choose 5 } = -42 $$

